# Alternate methods to save file instead of httpContext.response

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, web, httpcontext

In report handling, i've generated some file and given the report as output by using following code... I need the File to be saved in a dynamic path or i need an alternative method instead of `httpContext.response` so that i can save that file and can perform actions on that file. And is there any chance that we can protect files generated by `httpContext.response` by using password..?

```
 PSreport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("ReportSet", dataTable));
  byte[] psbytes = PSreport.Render(ReportFormat, "", out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);

            httpContext.Response.Clear();
            httpContext.Response.ContentType = mimeType;
            httpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + ReportName + "." + extension);
            httpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(psbytes, 0, pstbytes.Length);
            httpContext.Response.End();
```

Comment: This code sends some bytes to the user as a download. They can choose to save it to their machine or not, and they can choose where to save it. You have no control over that because it's the user's machine - you as the web application / browser have no permission to create files or folders there, and rightly so - if it was possible to do that, malicious sites would fill your hard drive with viruses and "humorous" cat videos. Some file formats such as ZIP can be protected with passwords, but that's specific to the file format and completely unrelated to the method of transmission.

Comment: Is there any chance to use another method instead of `httpContext.response` so that we can protect the file or save in some temporary file and then consume it through spire.xls or some other means..?

Comment: I'll repeat "Some file formats such as ZIP can be protected with passwords, but that's specific to the file format and **completely unrelated** to the method of transmission." httpContext.response is how you send the data, not how you protect it.

Comment: Bear in mind that in your code at the moment you don't actually have a file, just a stream of bytes. If your file format supports password protection (or other forms of encryption), you'd have to save the bytes to your server's disk as a file, apply protection to the file, then transmit that file in the response. If your format doesn't support encryption, you could consider wrapping in something which does (such as ZIP, for example). Then you have to consider the separate mechanism by which you make the password known to the user.